# How do I remove duckduckgo lens from Dash?

Tags: uninstall

Installed it using these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:w-vollprecht/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install duckduckgo-lens
```

What do I do to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge duckduckgo-lens
```

Also, if the PPA is not anymore necessary, you can remove it using:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:w-vollprecht/ppa
```

Then update with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See [`man apt-get`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) for more info.